# Javascript document.referrer empty

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for many threads but I could not find the solution. I would like to get document.referrer but it always show empty. Its been so confusing. Here is my code

```
<script>
alert(document.referrer);
</script>
```

I got that code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp). However, it is not work from my side. I have tried the code there and it works fine but not for mine.

I have an analysis that it is because my domain is under CloudFlare. Everyone knows that CloudFlare uses Proxy to redirect users before they go to our site but I would like to ask your opinion here. If it is not possible, is there any way I can do to pass http referrer? Thank you.

Comment: [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) is empty if you navigate from an `https` site to an `http` one, though even if I navigate from here to MDN it’s an empty string…

Comment: is there any way I can do to retrieve it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to retrieve the referral data if the host has set `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer` in their HTTP Header.

Since Cloudflare works as a reverse proxy it's not possible to get referral data in the same way as usual. [You can read more here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-)

Maybe Cloudflare keeps the data in your control panel, or you could find the correct data with tools like Google Analytics.